# Get a value in a single cell into multiple rows using SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

One particular field in the SQL Table has a value in the below format.

Value11,value12,Value13

Value21,value22,value23

...

...

I need to get each of the above lines in the text into individual lines using SSRS.
for example I will get 2 rows in the report for above data.
Is there a way to do this using a reporting project in VS or Report builder?

Thanks in advance.

Update

Hi,Below is the DDL for the table

tblTest

[id] int

[Description] VARCHAR(MAX)

Lets assume there is only one record with Below

Insert Into tblTest 
([id],[Description]) 
VALUES 
(1, 'Value11,value12,Value13

Value21,value22,value23')

So there is a carriage return Caharacter in above Insert for the Description column. This will have 2 lines in the description row.

So my requirement is that when i retrieve the data, I should get into below format.

ID, Description

1, Value11,value12,Value13

1, Value21,value22,value23

Comment: Gihan, is the grouping you are looking for always in the format "ValueN" where N is some single digit number? What is the criteria for making a new line? Are there other columns in this table? It would be helpful if you provided the DDL for the this table.

Comment: Please find the above update to the requirement. Thank you

Comment: you want the carriage return to be the delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `SELECT` for passing data to `Reporting Services`.

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.splittedDescriptions
FROM 
    (
        SELECT tblTest.id,
        CAST('<row>' + REPLACE(tblTest.[Description], CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '</row><row>') + '</row>' AS XML) as xmlRow 
        FROM tblTest
    ) t1
    CROSS APPLY
    ( 
        SELECT xmlTable.splittedRow.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as splittedDescriptions
        FROM t1.xmlRow.nodes('/row') AS xmlTable(splittedRow)
    ) t2
```

It uses `XML` and [`nodes()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) to split your description when it finds a `CRLF`.

It work with a single `CRLF`, if you need to work with double `CRLF` you can simply modify the `SELECT`.

Example - input data:

```
INSERT INTO tblTest ([id],[Description]) VALUES
    (1, 'val11, val12, val13' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'val21, val22, val23')
INSERT INTO tblTest ([id],[Description]) VALUES
    (2, 'val31, val32, val33')
INSERT INTO tblTest ([id],[Description]) VALUES
    (3, 'val41, val42, val43' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'val51, val52, val53' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'val61, val62, val63')
```

Example - output:

```
id          splittedDescriptions
----------- --------------------
1           val11, val12, val13
1           val21, val22, val23
2           val31, val32, val33
3           val41, val42, val43
3           val51, val52, val53
3           val61, val62, val63
```

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
select '1' as Id, Value11+','+value12+','+Value13 as Description into tblTest from XYZ;
```

Value11,value12,Value13   all should be in String